# Fetching API data asynchronously and making calls every 1 second

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, delay

I have a function:

```
func fetchHistoricalCurrencyData(completion: @escaping (() -> ())) {
    let g = DispatchGroup()
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        var historicalCurrencyDataTemp = [HistoricalCurrencyDataModel]()
        let dayDurationInSeconds: TimeInterval = 60*60*24
        for date in stride(from: self!.startingDate, to: self!.endingDate, by: dayDurationInSeconds) {
            g.enter()
            APIManager.shared.getHistoricalCurrencyData(date: self!.convertDateToStringDate(date: date), fromCurrency: String(self!.fromCurrency.prefix(3)), amount: self!.amount, toCurrency: String(self!.toCurrency.prefix(3))) {
                historicalCurrencyDataModel in
                historicalCurrencyDataTemp.append(historicalCurrencyDataModel)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    g.leave()
                }
            }
        }
        g.notify(queue:.main) {
            self?.historicalCurrencyData = DataManager.shared.getHistoricalCurrencyData(historicalCurrencyDataModels: historicalCurrencyDataTemp)
            print(self?.historicalCurrencyData)
            completion()
        }
        
    }
}
```

What's more, I have a dateRange which I divide into particular days within this range by using `stride()` function. Every day I get from this function I use to make an API Call to get desired data. Every API data I get is being converted to particular `HistoricalCurrencyDataModel` and appended to temp array which I create before the loop (`historicalCurrencyDataTemp`). When I receive all the data I want I use `DataManager` class to transform this data into `[String: Double]` dictionary which I finally assign to my `@Published var historicalCurrencyData: [String: Double]` variable.
One clue thing is that API I use make it possible to make API calls one after another at least after 1 second so I have to create 1 second delay between each call. I made it possible with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1)` statement. I control the whole flow of asynchronous operations with `DispatchGroup()`.
Unfortunately after all of this what I get is empty `Optional([:])` within `print(self?.historicalCurrencyData)` statement. And for example the correct behaviour would be that if I use dateRange with 5 days I get a dictionary with 5 entries.

Comment: Unrelated but this `DispatchQueue` closure does not cause a retain cycle. the `[weak self]` capture list is pointless.

Comment: Yes, API works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately got rid of all `DispatchQueues` and now it works as it should. I believe there was something wrong with the delay and not all values were fetched correctly. What's more, I discovered that there is no need of creating 1 second between API calls I thought otherwise after reading API documentation. I must have been wrong.

As suggested (which I agree with) I attach working code:

```
func fetchHistoricalCurrencyData(completion: @escaping (() -> ())) {
    let g = DispatchGroup()
    var historicalCurrencyDataTemp = [HistoricalCurrencyDataModel]()
    for date in stride(from: self.startingDate, to: self.endingDate, by: dayDurationInSeconds) {
        g.enter()
        APIManager.shared.getHistoricalCurrencyData(date: self.convertDateToStringDate(date: date), fromCurrency: String(self.fromCurrency.prefix(3)), amount: self.amount, toCurrency: String(self.toCurrency.prefix(3))) {
            historicalCurrencyDataModel in
            historicalCurrencyDataTemp.append(historicalCurrencyDataModel)
            g.leave()
        }
    }
    g.notify(queue:.main) {
        self.historicalCurrencyData = DataManager.shared.getHistoricalCurrencyData(historicalCurrencyDataModels: historicalCurrencyDataTemp)
        print(self.historicalCurrencyData)
        completion()
    }      
}
```

Comment: Actually, I think that someone having used `DispatchQueue` and having problems after seeing this question and my solution might connect the problem to this

Comment: Yes, it's a work around so other people viewing this might think of actual solution or at least get rid of the problem for a moment which in my case was enough

Comment: @Tibrogargan: It's a sincere attempt to answer the question, so it's fine. If it's not _useful_, it can be downvoted. Answers should be deleted if they're not making an attempt to answer the question (e.g., asking new questions, saying thank you, responding to other answers, &c.).

Comment: @JeremyCaney it's either that or "should be a comment on another post".  There is no real answer here, just commentary.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Actually this commentary is the answer. As said before it rather is a workaround rather than solution however it get rid of the main problem so should be posted as an answer imho

Comment: Yes, it should.  But you didn't actually do that, so this answer is currently just commentary.  Working code would be awesome.  Bonus points would be an explanation of what the issue was.

Comment: @Tibrogargan: This passed the [Low Quality Answers review on a 3-1 vote](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/31892989), with you being the lone dissent. If you believe the rest of the reviewers errored in our vote, you can use a custom flag to bring a moderator's attention to this. Alternatively, if you believe answers like this should be deleted, you might consider bringing the post to the attention of Meta Stack Overflow for discussion over policy interpretation.

Comment: @JeremyCaney You're entitled to your opinion, as am I.  I considered the answer borderline, and could be improved easily to the point where it's useful.  Frankly, the result of "75% of the people are Ok with this" is fine by me.  Would have liked to see the OP actually include some code to show exactly how they "got rid of all DispatchQueues", but c'est la vie.

Comment: I added working code as suggested in order to improve my 'answear' :)